# "Error: incomplete type "unsigned char[]" " when compiling with SUN C++ on Solaris machine

Tags: c++, linux, types, compilation, solaris

I have a definition of `unsigned char tmp[];` as a member of a structure.

When compiling with g++4 on Linux RedHat it does not complain. 
But when compiling with Sun C++ on Solaris 5.10 machine I get an error:

> Error: In this declaration "`tmp`" is of an incomplete type "`unsigned char[]`".

Are there any compile options for Sun C++ to make it compile?

I've read about the incomplete types, should I change it to a pointer? That would be problematic because I have many occurrences of the same kind of definitions.
Why is the difference in compilation results?

Comment: Is it the last member of the structure? This seems like a flexible array member at a glance.

Comment: yes, it is a last member of a structure. Is it not allowed in Solaris C++ compiler?

Comment: It is not allowed in C++ as a rule. GCC implements it as an extension. Making your code actually work will take a bit more effort than simply turning `tmp` into a pointer.

Answer (score 4):

Given the code

```
struct
{
    ...,
    char tmp[];
};
```

`tmp` is a [flexible array member](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member).

That is a C language construct that was [not valid in C++ until C++14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45193984/size-of-a-struct-with-flexible-array-member), but was supported as an extension by GCC.

The [latest version of Solaris Studio does support C++14 via the `-std=c++14` option.](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E77782_01/html/E77789/bkana.html#OSSCPgnaof)

Note that a zero-length array, such as

```
struct
{
    ...,
    char tmp[ 0 ];
};
```

is *not* the same as a flexible array member, and the `-features=zla` option may not be supported by your version of the Studio compiler.  It's [not supported by Solaris Studio 12.2, for example.](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18659_01/html/821-1383/bkana.html#bkapy)

Comment: Will -std=c++14 option allow the code compile itself without errors or will it only allow linking with the shared libraries compiled with C++14 standard? My current compiler is very old, so I wonder if upgrading to the latest one will solve my problem.

Comment: @angie  Updating to the latest compiler *should* solve this issue.  Without trying, it's hard to say if it will work on the code you're trying to compile.  GCC has a lot of extensions that tend to get used without the developers realizing they're using non-portable extensions.  You just found one example, and there may be more lurking in your code.

Comment: Update: I did upgrade to Studio 12.6 Sun C++ 5.15 SunOS_sparc 2017/05/30 but I still see the same error. When I try to use option -std=c99 compiler does not recognize it, while it is listed in -flags list. It says that it is ld option. Even when I use -xlang=c99 (which is accepted as compiler option) this error still exists.

Comment: @angie `-std=c99` looks like a C option, not a C++ one.  You need `-std=c++14`.